# Guardar Datos desde HTML5 con codigo PHP hacia MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas Tardes compañeros, deseo poder guardar datos en una tabla de Mysql,el problema esta en la parte de inserción de datos (INSERT INTO) ya que pongo una codigo de guardado directo y me guarda. pero al momento de mandar a llamar los datos desde SELECT de HTML (combo box) no manda a guardar.

(En esta parte formo un codigo php para llamar claves foraneas y asi poder rellenar la nueva tabla la cual ya esta conectada

```html
<?php
$server     = 'localhost'; //servidor
$username   = 'root'; //usuario de la base de datos
$password   = ''; //password del usuario de la base de datos
$database   = 'gym'; //nombre de la base de datos

$conexion = @new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conexion->connect_error) //verificamos si hubo un error al conectar, recuerden que pusimos el @ para evitarlo
{
    die('Error de conexión: ' . $conexion->connect_error); //si hay un error termina la aplicación y mostramos el error
}


$sql="SELECT * from clientes";
$result = $conexion->query($sql); //usamos la conexion para dar un resultado a la variable

if ($result->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $combobit="";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $combobit .=" <option value='        '>".$row['idCliente']."</option>";
         //concatenamos el los options para luego ser insertado en el HTML
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

$sql2="SELECT * from tipoperiodo";
$result2 = $conexion->query($sql2); //usamos la conexion para dar un resultado a la variable

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $combobit2="";
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $combobit2 .=" <option value='        '>".$row['idTipoPeriodo']."</option>";
         //concatenamos el los options para luego ser insertado en el HTML
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

$sql3="SELECT * from tipoperiodo";
$result3 = $conexion->query($sql3); //usamos la conexion para dar un resultado a la variable

if ($result3->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $combobit3="";
    while ($row = $result3->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $combobit3 .=" <option value='        '>".$row['Costo']."</option>";
         //concatenamos el los options para luego ser insertado en el HTML
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}
$conexion->close();

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Llenar un Combobox/Select con registros de una Tabla</title>
<link href="contactos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form class="" action="Guardarpagos.php" method="POST">

<label for="">Id de cliente</label>
   <select name="id" >
       <?php echo $combobit; ?>
   </select>
   
<label for="">Membresia</label>
   <select name="idTipoPeriodo">
       <?php echo $combobit2; ?>
   </select>

<label for=""> Costo de la Membresia  </label>
   <select name="costo">
       <?php echo $combobit3; ?>
   </select>

<label for=""   >Fecha de inicio</label>
 <input   name="inicio"   type="date">

   <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Enviar">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

luego para poder guardar ingreso este codigo en php

```html
<?php
 //conectamos Con el servidor
 $conectar=@mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
 //verificamos la conexion
 if(!$conectar){
  echo"No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor";
 }else{

  $base=mysql_select_db('gym');
  if(!$base){
   echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";
  }
 }
 //recuperar las variables
 $id=$_POST['id'];
 $idTipoPeriodo=$_POST['idTipoPeriodo'];
 $inicio=$_POST['inicio'];
 $costo=$_POST['costo'];

 //hacemos la sentencia de sql
$sql2= "INSERT INTO `gym`.`pagosclientes` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `costo`) VALUES (default, '$id', '$idTipoPeriodo','$inicio','$costo')";
  //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
 $ejecutar=mysql_query($sql2);
 //verificamos la ejecucion
 if(!$ejecutar){
  echo"Hubo Algun Error";
 }else{
  echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: La razon por la que no obtienes nada es porque estas dejando los `value` de las opciones en blanco.

Comment: Donde deberían de ir?

Comment: Deberia ser asi: `$combobit .=" <option value='" . $row['idCliente'] . "'>".$row['idCliente']."</option>";`

Comment: lo hago asi y me sigue dando el error

Comment: $sql="SELECT * from clientes";
$result = $conexion->query($sql); //usamos la conexion para dar un resultado a la variable

if ($result->num_rows > 0) //si la variable tiene al menos 1 fila entonces seguimos con el codigo
{
    $combobit="";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

$combobit .=" <option value='" . $row['idCliente'] . "'>".$row['idCliente']."</option>";


         //concatenamos el los options para luego ser insertado en el HTML
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No hubo resultados";
}

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: Listo! le quite los puntos a (default, '$id', '$idTipoPeriodo','$inicio','$costo')";
te agradezco muchisimo! antes lo tenia asi ".$id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuanto tratas de insertar datos tienes que tener en cuenta que los campos no este vacio y las variables esten definidas. Esto ayuda mucho porque no te permitira ingresar ningun dato a menos que cumplas con esa condicion.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['apellido'])){
    $add = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellido) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido)");
    $add->bindValue(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $add->bindValue(':apellido', $_POST['apellido']);
    $add->execute();

    echo "Los datos se ingresaron correctamente";
}
else{
    echo 'Error - Campos vacios';
}
```

}

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="nombre">
<input type="text" name="apellido">
<button name="add">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Primero utilizo sentencias preparadas que mejoran la seguridad y permiten la repetición de sentencias para una mejora del rendimiento. [Sentencias Preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Antes de insertar utilizo `isset` que compueba que las variables esten definidas, [isset manual php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) y tambien uso `empty` que determina si una variable está vacía, [empty manual php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php).

Esto es a modo de ejemplo y no esta mal saberlo para ir mejorando el codigo a medida que uno avanza.

En tu caso, el error esta en el `select` que no esta pasando bien los datos:

```
<select name="idTipoPeriodo">
   <option selected>Combos</option>
   <option value="<?=$combobit2;?>">Combo 2</option>
</select>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias me ha servido de mucho! :)